# Examples of universes with differents laws of physics

Tags: alternate-reality

Do you know examples of universes with a different self-consistent physics systems?

Not with minor changes, but another set of particles, interactions, with no light/matter/vacuum but other concepts etc...

Comment: Umm - would you care to rephrase this one? I've travelled to many different universes, but they all look the same to me. I'm pretty sure they all use the same physics. Or are you asking for examples of theoretical, self-consistent physics systems which have been worked out in detail?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I have edited. That's right. I am looking for coherent universes, with self-consistent physics systems. But not to the rewriting of the rules of our universe following a minor change or an addition.

Comment: This SE is for asking questions about your own fictional worlds. Asking about existing wolds in media is not in the spirit of this SE. If you want to know about scifi stories set in such universes, try the science fiction SE.

Comment: I'm not sure if we've answered "Do you know examples of universes" let alone what their physics looks like

Comment: Does "Conway's Game of Life" meet your criteria?  If not, why not?

Comment: I've put this on hold for now.  I went with "unclear", which already had several votes, though it also could be too broad or primarily opinion-based.  You're asking a broad question without criteria for evaluating answers.  Questions that ask for a list of X aren't a good fit for our format, either.  Please check out our short [tour].  Thanks.

Comment: Review the comments on [your earlier post](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/76201/universe-with-different-laws-of-physics).  In particular, **sandbox**.

Comment: @Mormacil Asking about already existing fictional universes is largely acceptable here, but the question must be able to stand on its own merits just the same as if it was a universe of your very own. We discussed this on [meta] some time ago, but I'm honestly not up to digging out the specific meta Q&A at the moment.

Comment: Here is a link to the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) that @JDługosz mentioned. You can write your question proposal as an answer to that post. Afterwards people in the chat will see that you posted a proposal and regular Meta users will see that there is a new question in the Sandbox. You can get feedback on the style there before releasing a question onto the main site. After ~24 hours you can normally post the question if there are no comments suggesting that bigger changes are needed.

Answer (score 4):

#### No

We don't even have a self-consistent model for our Universe, let alone one with different laws. I also take exception to your desire to exclude "minor changes". We have no idea what is "minor" and what is "major".

There are several examples of toy Universes such as [Abbott's Flatland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048627263X), but we have no idea what is and what isn't "adjustable". The closest I can think of for this question is to consider all of the (hundreds? thousands?) of alternatives that physicists are working on the bleeding edge of physics:

- brane theories
- supersymmetries
- Universes without Higgs bosons
- etc. etc.

Not too long ago we *"believed in"* a Universe which wasn't experiencing an accelerating expansion. Many of the discarded theories of yesterday are *almost* as consistent as today's. The idea that we can dial in different forms or values for the laws or the physical constants isn't something we can base on any science.

It's hard enough to discover/build laws that are consistent with the Universe around us. I have no idea how we would do that with some fictional (fantasy) Universe, do you?

Answer (score 0):

### *The Gods Themselves* by Isaac Asimov

This is one of the most complete examples of "different physical laws" I've seen.

In the book's parallel universe, the strong force is significantly more powerful than in ours; this means that solid matter can interpenetrate, and life has evolved to take advantage of this. Stars are also smaller and shorter-lived, which is what drives the main plot of the book: the inhabitants of the parallel universe are seeking an alternate source of energy for when their star dies. They end up trading matter back and forth with our own universe, using the difference in the laws to gain energy on both sides: stable isotopes in our universe are radioactive in theirs, and vice-versa, so they can be made to decay back and forth.

Comment: That is a parameter change, but still has vacuum, matter, etc. Just slightly different rules.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Raft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft_(novel)), by Stephen Baxter.

It's loosely part of his Xeelee sequence, but it's a standalone novel with few ties to the series. It examines life in a universe with much, much stronger gravity, strong enough that humans generate a significant gravitational field themselves, and humans living in a nebula of breathable air around a black hole.

Baxter has a degree in mathematics, a doctorate in engineering, and has taught maths and physics; he does hard sci-fi incredibly well.

Comment: That universe has a “minor change” and still has gravity, vqcuum, matter, light, etc.